# Can one represent divergent integrals or germs at infinity with surreal numbers?

Tags: surreal-numbers, divergent-integrals

I have been disliking the theory of surreal numbers for a while, but let's test it.

So, we have a set of divergent improper integrals of continuous functions with the following ordering: $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx\ge\int_0^\infty g(x)dx$ if $\int_0^s (f(x)-g(x))dx\ge0$ for all $s$ greater than some large $S$. And all convergent integrals are considered equal to their sums.

Using surreal numbers can you give representations of such set of divergent integrals?

Comment: The papers [Transseries as germs of surreal functions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.01995), [Integration on the Surreals: a Conjecture of Conway, Kruskal and Norton](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.02478), and arguably [On numbers, germs, and transseries](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.06936) might be relevant. Even if they don't answer your question, maybe they can help focus it?